# jquery mobile does not execute the Script on the response of ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on jQuery Mobile and currently stumbled upon a road block

On render to "task" index page after successfully creating the "Task"(I accordance with rails App) the index page compromise of `ul#listview` with count bubble  some thing of this is [kind](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-count.html)  . On the beneath the page there is the script to to get the count  as seen in the bubble example (mention above) but it seem that script never execute.

Here is the Code:

**partials  => _index.html.erb**

```
<div data-role="page" id="task">
 <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
 </div>
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
       <a href="/mytasks"> My Task 
         <span class="ui-li-count" id="my_tasks" ></span>
       </a>
        </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/alltasks"> All Task 
         <span class="ui-li-count" id="all_tasks" ></span>
       </a>
    </li>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#task").live("pageinit",function() {
       alert("Update the count");
       // The below method fetched the count 
       go_fetch_the_count("mytasks","all_tasks");
     })
  </script>
</div>
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // above function // }) ,
    $("#task").live("pagecreate",function(){ // above function // })
    $("#task").live("pageshow",function(){ // above function // })
    $("#task").live("pagebeforecreate",function(){ // above function // })
```

But it seem not even the alert is also not executed.

Regards
Viren Negi

Comment: First you're missing the closing </ul> tag, second go_fetch_the_count("mytasks","all_tasks"); does mytasks need to map to id="my_tasks"? Third do you have a demo site or http://jsfiddle.net you could add to your question

Comment: @Jasper The missing UL is not the problem - maybe the OP isn't using the current JS files or something

Comment: @K.Bob I didn't mean to infer that was the problem, I just posted a code example so Viren could see that the code worked fine.

Comment: @Jasper No worries, I think there must be something else he's not showing us.

Comment: @Phil the go_fetch_the_count() is javascript method to make and ajax request get the json response and the update the according span as visible in example

Comment: @Jasper thank for Example in jsfiddle but it seem that you got it wrong I said when I render the above page as ajax response without(it something like render :partial => "name_of_partial" in Rails Terminology)  template/layout the javascript doesn't execute even though binding all the event mention above

Comment: @Jasper ,@K.Bob , I have push the app at http://jquery-mobile.heroku.com/  to see the effect got to new page and submit the form and see the count is not getting updated

Comment: I see now what you mean. The first time the page is shown the get_count() function runs. When you add a new car and go back to the listing page the get_count() function does NOT run. Is that what the problem is ?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html Have you tried turning off the default ajax post/link behaviour, so that when you return to the list you get a 'new' page.

Comment: @K.Bob ,Yes that is right , but as mention in a  separate comment address to you I mention that jQuery mobile is inject the same page in dom again (if you inspect the dom using firefug or dom inspector) that same div id="car_list" is inject again without flushing the old div from the dom so now my focus is to remove the old div id="car_list" before jQuery Mobile inject the response in into the om I hope I'm not confusing you

Comment: And Yes Turning off the default ajax can help on this but I don't want to follow that path because of various scenario like bandwidth.

Comment: The 'old' `car_list` is still in the DOM but is no longer active, you can find the active `car_list` as it will also have the `ui-page-active` class which the old one no longer does. I find the jQM caching to be troublesome and tend to switch it off - I don't find bandwidth to be enough of a problem these days.

Comment: Yes I think I got the way by removing the page from the dom after pagehide  event occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solution for above problem I manage to find out

**SOLUTIONS**

1. Remove the Page from the dom  through *pagehide* event so that there is only **one dom** in the page with **same dom id** .
   something like this

> $('#car_list').live('pagehide',function() {
>
> ```
>       $(this).remove(); 
>
>     });
> ```

(The approach has a serious caveat if you have jquery-mobile back functionality enable. It might land you on page whose back page would have been **removed by the page hide event** living the user in no man land situation . Plus to remove and download a page again just because the  bubble count got change in the page is a very hard trade off that where the second solution worked for me)

1. This solution defined the global variable on the page and every time the **get_count** method is called it check whether the global variable is define **if yes** update the current page with count just the way the old page is updated

   ```
   function get_count() {
      $.ajax( { 
            url:'/get_count.json',
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(result) {
              $.each(['fer','lam','fia','cor','mer'],function(index,value) {
                 console.log(window.reloaded);
                 // the below if statement will only execute for the second time 
                 if (window.reloaded && typeof(window.reloaded) != "undefined") {
                   console.log("hello");
                   $(".ui-page-active").find("#"+value).text(result[value]) 
                 }
                 $("#"+value).text(result[value]);
              })
              window.reloaded = true ;  
            }
        });
      }
   ```

Update the code with the 2nd solution in heroku app too.

**Accepting this as valid answer until some provide more better way to achieve the same**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</ul>` tag. But even without this works OK for me.
You don't have a template/layout with another `data-role=page` in it do you?

This code works for me (including the missing UL)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 

    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id='jQMpage' data-role="page" data-theme='e'>


 <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
 </div>
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview">

    <li>
       <a href="/mytasks"> My Task 
         <span class="ui-li-count" id="my_tasks" ></span>
       </a>
        </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/alltasks"> All Task 
         <span class="ui-li-count" id="all_tasks" ></span>
       </a>

    </li>

</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#jQMpage").live("pageinit", function () {
          alert("Update the count");
      })
  </script>


    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware that the layout is not render as I'm only returning the above div with data-role="page" for the ajax response for sake reducing the bandwidth , But for sake is there a way to achieve the same without rendering layout

Comment: It seem that the issue is that jquery inject the same page in dom event though the page exist in the dom (does not remove the old (use dom inspector to observe it)) in the example the event is fired but the not update on the current page put page that previously exists in dom hence the problem. "Now my focus is to remove that old page from the dom and inject the new page (Can this be achieved or am I sound over ambition's)"